# scrapy setting is not existed

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have this line of code in my spider

```
settings.overrides['JOBDIR']= self.domain+"_"+self.Category+"_"+self.Action
```

I got this error:

```
__
    settings.overrides['JOBDIR']= self.domain+"_"+self.Category+"_"+self.Action
NameError: global name 'settings' is not defined
```

I run my spider from a script like this:

```
def setup_crawler(domain):
    spider = GeneralSpider(xmlFile=domain)
    settings = get_project_settings()
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    crawler.start()
```

Comment: What does your `get_project_settings()` do?

Comment: @warunsl no idea. Do you imply to use it insead of setting?

Comment: @warunsl thanks a lot. that works. write an answer to accept it please.

Comment: @warunsl look it works by not giving me an error, but the jobdir directly is not being created. why please?

Answer (score 0):

`get_project_settings()` looks for the environment variable `SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE` to be set. Make sure it is set in your environment. The documentation [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#designating-the-settings) explains how to set it.