# Cannot change directory to a script using bash - cron

Tags: python, linux, bash, cron, scrapy

I have a script that runs multiple instances of Python Scrapy crawlers, Crawlers are int `/root/crawler/batchscript.py`

and in `/root/crawler/` I have that scrapy crawler.

Crawlers are working perfectly fine.

batchscript.py looks like this, (posting only relevent code)

```
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from amazon_crawler.spiders.amazon_scraper import MySpider

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
```

When I run `batchscrip.py` inside `/root/crawler/` directory scraper runs fine.

But when I run it from outside of this directory using `python /root/crawler/batchscript.py` then it does not run as intended, (Settings are not imported correctly), `get_project_settings()` are empty.

**I have tried creating a BASH script too**
I create bash script called `batchinit.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
alias batchscript="cd /root/crawler/"
python batchscript.py
```

and behaviour is same :(

> When I run `batchinit.sh` inside `/root/crawler/` directory scraper
>   runs fine.
>
> But when I run it from outside of this directory using `bash 
>   /root/crawler/batchinit.sh` then it does not run as intended,
>   (Settings are not imported correctly), `get_project_settings()` are
>   empty.

**Why I am doing it? What is ultimate goal?**

I want to create a cronjob for this script. I tried to schedule cronjobs using above mentioned commands but I have issues as mentioned above.

Comment: What are you trying to do by defining the alias in the shell script? Why not just put cd /root/crawler/ on that line instead of aliasing it to batchscript?

Comment: Where are `scrapy` and `amazon_crawler` modules? Are them in a virtual env?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22466264/2874789

Comment: @ChristopherShroba I am newbie to shell scripting ... id wrote simple cd command but it didnt work ...

Comment: See: [How do I “cd” in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/431684/3776858)

Comment: just to shed some light on the bash script, the line `alias batchscript="cd /root/crawler"` doesn't actually do a `cd` -- it simply sets up an alias `batchscript` which will cd to that directory if it's run as a bash command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using bash, you could always do:

```
cd /root/crawler && python batchscript.py
```

it's always good policy to use absolute paths to programs/executables referenced in cron jobs.